# Is there a comparing tool able to merge line by line?

Tags: svn, merge, compare, tortoisesvn, kdiff3

Currently I use kdiff with tortoise to compare files before commit.

I'm searching for a tool that compares files and is able to merge (undo) a change like by line.

The best example is when I add a temporary dump while coding and forget about it. When I'm about to commit I use tortoise's compare to see what has changed and note that dump. Currently I must go to the file, find it and delete it. The tool I'm looking for would just let me undo/remove/merge that line alone, from the original repo file to the working copy file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=de) is very powerful tool and can be integrated in *Tortoise*. For Line by Line Merge I like the integrated merging tool of [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/index.htm). Downside on Total Commander is the missing *Tortoise* integration.

Comment: Thanks! I tested WinMerge and it pwns! I just use Alt+down to move thru differences and Alt+right to remove changes that aren't in Repo! I can even Ctrl+Z to undo merges lol! Its graphs and highlights are also great. Only thing I miss is not being able to use WinExplorer Context Menu to mark a file and then select another file to compare, as we can do with kdiff.